# Allocating prizes in tournament with ties using R and data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm dealing with tournament results in R where ties can happen. Say two players tie for 3rd place. They would share (3rd_prize + 4th_prize), and each earn (3rd_prize + 4th_prize)/2. If 10 players tie for third place, they would split the sum of 3rd through 13th place, and each get that sum over 10.

Given this structure, and given a data.table listing all players, their absolute results, and how many people they drew with, how could we generate a column with everyone's winnings? I don't know how to format sample data in the post, so I'm attaching a link to a google sheet with sample data and a desired result if that's okay!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fLUZ172Sl_yXVQE3VI0Xo4wSr_SRvaL43MCZIMYen2w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you can type out the dataset like how you used to do it in your previous question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 options:

#### (1)

```
prizes[results[, rn:=.I], on=.(Position=rn)][,
    .(Person, Winnings=sum(Prize) / .N), .(Position=i.Position)]
```

Explanation:

1. Create a sequence of row index for results using `results[, rn:=.I]`
2. Then left join this results and prize table using row index `prizes[results[, rn:=.I], on=.(Position=rn)]`
3. Then using the result from step 2, group by Position in results and calculate average prize for each Person (i.e. `[,.(Person, Winnings=sum(Prize) / .N), .(Position=i.Position)]`.

Assumption is that `results` is already sorted by Position.

#### (2)

Assuming that each row in `results` receives a prize in the same row in `prizes`, you can calculated average prizes after extracting using indexing:

```
results[, Winnings := sum(prizes$Prize[.I], na.rm=TRUE) / .N, Position]
```

output:

```
    Position Person Winnings
 1:        1      A    100.0
 2:        2      B     50.0
 3:        3      C     17.5
 4:        3      D     17.5
 5:        4      E      5.0
 6:        5      F      4.0
 7:        6      G      3.0
 8:        7      H      1.0
 9:        7      I      1.0
10:        7      J      1.0
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
results <- data.table(Person=LETTERS[1:10], 
    Position=c(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7), 
    tied=c(1,1,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,3))
prizes <- data.table(Position=1:10, 
    Prize=c(100,50,25,10,5,4,3,2,1,0))
```

Comment: Wow, this seems really clever to me. I can't follow the first one, but the second one works because of course for the first "prize" that would be paid out to a given position (group of ties), it has to be in the same row in the prize spreadsheet as the person is on the results spreadsheet, right? I don't know how to word that better, sorry that's really unclear.

I haven't come across the .I much before, I think I need to start incorporating that.